# Open Colon delimited file from command line in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I want to create a shortcut or a command to open a file that uses a colon : as a delimiter in excel.

I know via the UI I can

- click "From Text/CSV"
- select a file
- click Import
- select a delimiter (colon)
- click load and it works as I would expect.

Or alternatively from the UI

- Open the file
- Data-> Text to Columns, wizard pops up
- Select Delimited [Next]
- Delimiter [x] other value : [Next]
- Finish
- Desired View

I can do

`excel.exe sample.csv`

and open a csv file fine I would like to do something like

if you do the obvious

`excel.exe colonDelimFile.dat`

the entire row ends up in a single cell

So I would like to run some command like this that opens the colon Delimited File in excel as expected like below but I cannot find the arguments or commands.

`excel.exe <some args> colonDelimFile.dat`

even something like

```
<command to set delims>
excel.exe colonDelimFile.dat
<command to restore delims
```

or something similar. I cant seem to find any good documentation on excel from the command line for others here is what I have found:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6

I also know that you can specify the separator in the file itself by putting this as the first line

`sep=:`

But I want to leave the file unmodified except for any changes the user makes and saves to the file in terms of values.

Comment: The only way this can be easily scripted, is by creating a new file by first echoing sep=: to it, then echoing the other file into the same file.

Comment: yeah I think that's the only way as well but I am hoping there is some knowledge I dont have or some secret command line args

Comment: There is of course always the option to just set it right in excel so the file opens and doesn't need conversing. You can do this in regional settings.